# android how do i crete folder and show on screen

Tags: android

I'd like to create a gallery folder in internal memory like in the screenshot below:

[image]

When click on an album, I want it to show the list of images inside it.

```
String dirPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "newfoldername";
File projDir = new File(dirPath);
```

Comment: I guess that this is just a `LinearLayout` with four `ImageViews` which is set dynamically depending on the data when the images where captured. It's not actually a visual representation of a folder.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a folder for your app here is code below which takes String name of your folder and checks if SD card is available and if it is creates a folder of that name in pictures folder else if Sd card is not present then creates the folder with same name in the internal memory where app is installed like data/data.com.myapp/files/yourFolder

```
public File createDirectoryForApp(Context con, String dirName)
{
File directory=null;
    /*
     * This sections checks the phone to see if there is a SD card. if
     * there is an SD card, a directory is created on the SD card 
     */

    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {

         // search for directory on SD card
        directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                + "/"+dirName+"/");

        // if no directory exists, create new directory to store test
        // results
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }

    } 
    else
    {
          //create new file directory object in internal memory as no SD card is available
        directory = new File(con.getFilesDir()
                + "/"+dirName+"/");

        // if no directory exists, create new directory
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();
        }


    }
    return directory;
        }

//method used above to check external storage
 public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and to get files with specific extension and further files in inner directories(which are also files)  you can use following method

```
private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
    } else {
        if(file.getName().endsWith(".png")){
            inFiles.add(file);
        }
    }
}
return inFiles;
}
```

and to visually represent all this information it depends on you that how you design your layout and display the data after getting from these files.

Comment: i create folder in my memory using this String dirPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "picture";
File projDir = new File(dirPath);  
my folder name is "picture" how do i show on picture folder ons creen  ?not is content

Comment: As far as i know there is no single line code which gives you display of your directory info like you mentioned in above picture.. you can use second method to get files in your directory and then display the info from these files to your custom layout designed according to above picture